# How does maximumAge of GetGeopositionAsync work?

Tags: c#, caching, windows-phone-8

One of the overloaded method of `Geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync()` takes 2 parameters. `maximumAge` and `timeout`. I got the use of timeout. But concept of maximumAge is still unclear to me.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh973537.aspx) says:
**The maximum acceptable age of cached location data.**
If I set maximumAge to `TimeSpan.FromHours(1)`, which of the following does it mean?

- In a active session of my app, if I request again for location, it will return from cache
- If I restart my app and then query for location, and time since last query is still less than an hour, it will return from cache.
- If some other app has requested for location in last one hour and my app requests for location, it will return from cache.

Basically my question is, is the cache storing the location is maintained for a

1. particular session of the app
2. app as a whole, i.e. for all sessions
3. or its global